# SQL Multiple Table Into Custom Object

Tags: sql, join

I have 10 Tables which all belong to one object "Customer".
A "maintable" which got the indexfields (like name, surname...) and 9 tables which could hold several rows for each customer (addresstable with several addresses for one customer for example).

Now I want to create an custom object which holds all indexfields (dictionary) and tables (with rows and so on).

How do fetch the SQL-Data most efficiently? I think simple joins would result in a very big resultset because of the 10 tables.

The number of rows in the 9 tables are dynamic too.

Comment: Define 'fetch', Define 'most efficiently'. Define 'very big'.

Comment: @onedaywhen There are 50000 customers. Lets say for each of the 9 "table"-tables 5 rows per customer. this would be 5^9 * 50000 rows. Or not? Im quite bad at Sql ;)

Comment: OK so you select 97 billion rows in a SQL query ("very big" - agreed): now what do you want to do with this SQL result set? a.k.a. Define "fetch".

Comment: Process it into a custom object. I just fetched every table by itself and then processed it.